# Page not loading during first click on link - Framework7

Tags: javascript, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap, html-framework-7

Am playing with Framework7 for mobile app development.

Am facing a small issue now. I have the following setup:

```
var $$ = Dom7;

var app  = new Framework7({

    //.....



    routes: routes
});

var homeView = app.views.create('#view-home', {
  url: '/'
});

var settingsView = app.views.create('#view-settings', {
    url: '/settings/'
});
```

And now I have created a new page inside `/pages/new-msg.html` with the following content:

```
<div class="page" data-name="new-msg">
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner sliding">
            <div class="left">
                <a href="#" class="link back">
                    <i class="icon icon-back"></i>
                    <span class="ios-only">Back</span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="title">Create New Message</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="block block-strong">
            testing...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my `routes.js` is like this:

```
routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    url: './index.html',
  },
  {
    path: '/new-msg/',
    url: './pages/new-msg.html',
  },

  //.......

];
```

And inside my `index.html` (my home page), I have created a FAB button like this:

```
<div class="fab fab-right-bottom color-red">
    <a href="/new-msg/" class="link">
        <i class="icon f7-icons">add</i>                                                        
    </a>
</div>
```

The problem is, when I click on the FAB button(add button) at runtime, on the first click it won't open up the `New Msg` page. But if I click on the button again, it opens up. And if press back button(from the `New Msg` page) and clicks on the button again(single time) it opens up without issues.

So, only during the first time, the first click doesn't open up the `New Msg` page. I think its not loaded to the DOM ? Is there any workaround for this so that I can open it up in the first click itself?

Thank you

Comment: pleas create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Check her for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: can you make fiddle of this.

Comment: check here https://framework7.io/docs/action-sheet.html

Comment: make sure you didn' put any restriction in css file with using selector which effect on your html element

Comment: Does it have a (hidden) javascript `hover`/`mouseover`/`mouseenter` state? If so, WebKit-browsers (Safari, Android browser) make you click twice (first click triggers the hover, such as tooltips or animation).

Comment: I had the same issue when I was working with angular and ionic. Its not that you are missing anything, but this cannot be resolved without a live example or a fiddle. All I can suggest you is to check the opacity of your link button which seems to be overlapped by some other html element at initial page load. It is one of the major issues with phonegap/hybrid apps.

Comment: same code works fine in our test app. try to make fiddle. that give a lot of insight on the problem you are facing

Comment: Sorry guys, I got it resolved from their support forum : http://forum.framework7.io/t/resolved-page-not-loading-during-first-click-on-link-framework7/3745/9 I posted the question there since I wasn't getting much solutions from here and I was in a damn tight situation. Thanks to all who commented here.